# SWI-Prolog No permission to modify static procedure `set_prolog_flag/2' in init.pl

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to modify the initial configuration of SWI-Prolog in command line, following the official documentation from SWI-Prolog FAQ [1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html) and [2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/PlInitialisation.html) to change the output displayed. However, I have run into this error:

```
X@X:~/Documents/Prolog$ swi-prolog.swipl
ERROR: /home/X/snap/swi-prolog/55/.config/swi-prolog/init.pl:1:
ERROR:    No permission to modify static procedure `set_prolog_flag/2'
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.4.3)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.
```

The file init.pl is a one liner:

```
set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options, [quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(18)]).
```

All the information I found was that the error could be related to a [system-defined flag that is not marked changeable](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=set_prolog_flag/2), since other entries in this forum for `No permission to modify static procedure` are more related to syntax error.

---

*I'm new to prolog, helps and suggestions are welcomed!*

Comment: Add `:-` in front to make it a directive.

Comment: @false That solved the issue, do you want to post it as an answer to marked it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to redefine `set_prolog_flag/2` as a fact.

Add `:-`  in front of it to make it a directive.